# Kentor Owin middleware in .Net webform GetExternalLoginInfo() return null

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, owin-middleware, kentor-authservices

I am using Kentor Owin middleware in .Net webform and I can see Idp returning SAML with assertions but the code below always return null.

var loginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo();

I can see ".../AuthServices/Acs" is returning error=access_denied parameter when it do redirect.

Anyone know what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the Owin/Katana logging and check the output. AuthServices will write a detailed error message to the log.